# CMake execute_process of shell scripts through bash on windows eats exit codes

Tags: cmake

I am using this CMake in an attempt to run a cross-platform shell script during configuration stage:

```
   find_program(BASH_EXECUTABLE bash
        NAMES bash git-bash
        HINTS
            "C:/Program Files/Git/bin"
        REQUIRED
    )


    execute_process (
        COMMAND ${BASH_EXECUTABLE} "exit1.sh"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE RESULTSV_OUT
        ERROR_VARIABLE RESULTSV_ERR
        ECHO_OUTPUT_VARIABLE
        ECHO_ERROR_VARIABLE
        RESULT_VARIABLE RESULTSV_VARY
    )
    message("MESSAGE OUTPUT IS ${RESULTSV_OUT}" )
    message("MESSAGE ERROR IS ${RESULTSV_ERR}" )
    message("MESSAGE RESULTS IS ${RESULTSV_VARY}" )
```

result is always:

```
1> [CMake] MESSAGE OUTPUT IS 
1> [CMake] MESSAGE ERROR IS 
1> [CMake] MESSAGE RESULTS IS 0
```

even though exit1.sh is just a file that says

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
exit 1
```

The command does run and I have been able to confirm it with larger scripts.  It runs in a new bash window but I do not understand why CMake is unable to obtain this exit code from bash.

`COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL` also seems unable to recognize that the command failed.

Comment: message(BASH_EXECUTABLE) returns ""
message(${BASH_EXECUTABLE}) returns "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe"

Comment: It seems to work correctly if I do this instead             set(ENV{PATH} "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/;${PATH}") - and then I just call  execute_process (COMMAND bash ... as if it is known and don't use find_program which is confusing to me

Comment: Are you sure git-bash.exe is the bash executable? [Is it not actually the terminal emulator executable](https://superuser.com/q/1104567/1749748)? Don't you actually want to run bash instead of the terminal emulator? Why do you pass `NAMES bash git-bash`?

Comment: Looks like this was a cached value stored by find_program as this confused me too.  An earlier version used the value "C:/Program Files/Git/" for the path.  My mistake for not clearing the cache earlier.  It works fine with bash.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `git-bash.exe` is the terminal emulator wrapper for Git Bash (it starts a Mintty terminal with Git-Bash's Bash as the shell). See also https://superuser.com/q/1104567/1749748. Instead of `NAMES bash git-bash`, you should just pass `NAMES bash`.

Note that you may have to re-configure your buildsystem after that change / reconfigure it with a fresh CMake cache, since `find_program` caches the result of what it finds by default (or you can turn off its caching with `NO_CACHE`, but read the warning label in [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) on why you probably don't want to do that (perf reasons)).